# how to work with prais.winsten results in stargazer and broom (r)

Tags: r, regression, glm, stargazer, broom

The package `"prais"` contains the function `prais.winsten` to run a regression models with Prais Winsten estimator. However, neither `stargazer` nor `broom` packages seem to work with the results from the `prais.winsten` function.

After fitting a model of the form

```
pw<- prais.winsten(speed ~ dist, cars)
```

When I try to report the results with stargazer I get the following error:

```
stargazer(pw, out = "pw.html") 
Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
```

and likewise tidying the model with the `broom` package I get

```
tidy(pw)
Error in names(object) <- nm : 
  'names' attribute [1] must be the same length as the vector [0]
```

Is there any way to work with `prais.wisten` results in `stargazer` and `broom`?

Or alternatively, is there any way to run a Prais Winsten estimator in `glm`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to edit the Prais.Winsten function to return an lm object.

`getAnywhere(prais.winsten())`will return the function. You can then copy the code into your script and just change return function from "results" to "lm".

Comment: That works, but how can I include the additional model statistics (i.e. Rho Rho.t.statistic and Iterations) into the stargazer table?

Comment: This solution doesn't work anymore with the new version `prais_winsten()`.